# How can i get all the results using Mongodb Left join as well as conditions?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have two tables. 1) roomList 2) roomUser. Here left table will be roomList.  Is it possible to fetch all the results even if the joined table result is empty ?

I am current using aggregation: $lookup, $unwind, $match.

> roomList

```
const roomInfo = new mongoose.Schema({
    roomName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    currentMembers: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    createdBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: "User"
    },
    creationDate: {
        type: Date,
        trim: true
    },
    status: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 1
    }
});
```

> roomUser

```
const roomUser = new mongoose.Schema({
    roomId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: "RoomInfo"
    },
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: "User"
    },
    joiningDate: {
        type: Date,
        trim: true
    },
    leavingDate: {
        type: Date,
        trim: true
    },
    requestDate:{
        type:Date,
        trim:true
    },
    status: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0 
    }
```

I want the result similar to this mysql query.

> SELECT * FROM roomList LEFT JOIN roomUser ON roomUser.roomId =
>       roomList.id WHERE roomUser.userId = 123 AND roomList.status = 1.

Comment: I finally figure out, it's so hard (banging head) to solve this problem using so called JOIN. I did it using Mongoose Sub-document. Now my collection look like this:

Answer (score 0):

MongoDb and noSql database do not have the same philosophy, as SQL database.

For SQL database, we should create two tables to store roomlist a roomUser.
On a NoSQL database, you should store the user data on the roomlist, on a special entries (Array, new object), or create a new table, to store the link between users and the roomlist.

After that, you should be able to make your query.

Best regards

Comment: ok i understand your answer. But what if i want to use ROOMUSER collection for my another purpose like delete few selected users from a specific room without complex logic then what will be the procedure ?

Answer (score 0):

it can be done with multiple aggregation stages.

1. $match by roomUser id
2. $lookup by room_id
3. $unwind the found rooms
4. $match the status
5. $replaceRoot to promote the rooms

```java
db.roomUser.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "_id": ObjectId("5d3473a686041613147424ad")
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "roomList",
            "localField": "room_id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "r"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$r"
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "r.status": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": "$r"
        }
    }
])
```

i don't know mongoose, hopefully you can come up with the mongoose equivalent...

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure out, it's so hard (banging head) to solve this problem using so called JOIN. I did it using Mongoose Sub-document. Now my collection looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const roomUsers = new Schema (
    {
        userId: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            ref: "User"
        },
        joiningDate: {
            type: Date,
            trim: true
        },
        leavingDate: {
            type: Date,
            trim: true
        },
        requestDate:{
            type:Date,
            trim:true
        },
        status: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0 // 0 for none, 1 for request, 2 for joined, 3 for blocked
        }
    }
);

const roomInfo = new mongoose.Schema({
    roomName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    currentMembers: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    createdBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: "User"
    },
    creationDate: {
        type: Date,
        trim: true
    },
    status: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 1 // 1 for active, 2 for deactive
    },
    roomUsers:[roomUsers]
});

var roomInfp = mongoose.model("RoomInfo", roomInfo);
module.exports = roomInfp;
```